# How to convert my slide menu like foursquare menu?

Tags: android, layout, dashboard, sliding

Right now I have a sliding menu as follows,

[image]

I want to style it like foursquare sliding menu,

[image]

Here is my layout

> ```
>   <RelativeLayout
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>       <Button
>           android:id="@+id/oneButton"
>           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
>              android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
>           android:text="@string/duo_dashboard" />
>
>       <Button
>           android:id="@+id/twoButton"
>           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>           android:layout_below="@+id/oneButton"
>           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_settings"
>           android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
>           android:text="@string/title_settings" />
>
>        <Button
>           android:id="@+id/threeButton"
>           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>           android:layout_below="@+id/twoButton"
>           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_todo"
>           android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
>           android:text="@string/title_todo" />
>
>   </RelativeLayout>
> </LinearLayout> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: could you please give more details on what you are trying to do?
do you want to replicate the colors? or the whole style?

Comment: i want to apply the style with the line shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a raw guess here. The line splitter can probably be achieved by the divider property like so.

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/gradientshape" <!--thats what im talking about-->
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
```

Where gradientshape must be a gradient xml file like so

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/dark_black" <!--use whatever colors you like-->
    android:endColor="@color/light_grey"
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="270" /> </shape>
```

EDIT: Just looked at the foursquare resources the coloring and line shadows are actually achieved by a 9 patch image

Answer (score 1):

Provided by Android: 
Displaying the navigation drawer

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: am already using sliding menu library for this, was asking about the styling this cant be an answer